# Definition of heat

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, definition

> Heat is defined as any spontaneous flow of energy from one object to another,
> caused by a difference in temperature between the objects. We say that “heat”
> flows from a warm radiator into a cold room, from hot water into a cold ice cube,
> and from the hot sun to the cool earth. The mechanism may be different in each
> case, but in each of these processes the energy transferred is called “heat.” -
> Schroeder, Page 18, An introduction to Thermal Physics

Here there are two definitions of heat are given, first is the flow of energy due to temperature difference, and the other is the amount of energy transferred due to temperature difference.

Which one is correct?

Comment: That's the same...

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent not necessarily, flow is ambiguous here, is it energy flux? Is it dE/dt?

Comment: The word flow there is the same as transferred. "The amount of energy that had flowed due to temperature difference."

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent I see, thank you

Comment: Can’t an object just be hot without transferring its heat? Why does heat need to “flow”? The whole point of a well-insulated thermos bottle is that its heat stays inside, at least for quite a while.

Comment: @Ghoster an object can be "hot" without transferring heat if it is in thermal equilibrium with its environment.  And note that the English language doesn't help in this subject area.  Heat is not "hot", it is a form of energy transfer between objects of different temperature.  In other words, the same amount of heat transfer can occur between a very cold object and an even colder environment, or between a hot object and a hot environment that demonstrates the same temperature difference as in the cold case.

Comment: @DavidWhite My point is that I think heat should be introduced as the kinetic energy of the random thermal motion of atoms and molecules, not as anything related to the flow or transfer of energy.

Comment: @Ghoster when there is a temperature difference between objects, there is a transfer of kinetic energy from the atoms or molecules of the hotter object to the atoms or molecules of the colder object.  Also, I agree with your idea of heat but most physics types do not (note: I have an engineering background).

Comment: @DavidWhite Yes, of course. But good thermal insulation can make the rate of energy transfer arbitrarily small, so it seems silly to insist that energy transfer, rather than simply thermal energy itself, is the most important concept when thinking about heat. I am a physicist, not an engineer.

Comment: @Ghoster heat is to thermal energy as work is to mechanical energy. All four concepts are important and distinct.

Comment: @Dale OK, thanks. Thermodynamics was never one of my strong points.

Comment: @Dale an even better way: thermal work (transport of entropy) is to thermal energy as to gravitational work (transport of mass) is to gravitational energy as to pressure work (transport of volume) is to pressure energy, etc., while "evolved heat" is dissipated work.

Answer (score 2):

> Here there are two definitions of heat are given, first is the flow of
> energy due to temperature difference, and the other is the amount of
> energy transferred due to temperature difference.

There is no difference between the two.

The first describes the mechanism for transferring energy between substances of different temperature, the other describes the amount of energy transferred due to the temperature difference. Either way, the definition differentiates heat from  the other form of energy transfer in thermodynamics, namely work,  where work is the transfer of energy due to force times displacement.

Hope this helps.